# Which Java Method will be called (Inheritance, No @Override)

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have the following classes:

```
Class X 
{
    void f() { ... }
}

Class Y extends X 
{
    void f() {....}
}

Class Z extends Y 
{
    // No void f() method declared here
}
```

Calling `f()` on an object of `Z` causes `Y.f()` to be executed. I'd expect that `X.f()` would be executed, since `Y.f()` has no `@Override` Annotation.

My question: Will the most specific method always be executed, or what's the reason for this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: All inheritable instance methods in Java are virtual. Overriding is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Override annotation is optional. It is not required to use it in order for a method of the sub-class to override a method of the base-class that has the same signature.

Using the `@Override` annotation just helps to catch typos. For example, if the overriding method doesn't have the exact name as the method it is supposed to override, the compiler will complain that the is no matching method to override. Without the annotation, the compiler doesn't know that you intend to override a base-class method.

So, yes, the most specific method will always be executed, as long as it has a sufficient access level (in your example, if `Y`'s `f()` was private, `X`'s `f()` would be executed instead).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if no specific label Override all you'd be doing is creating a new method